# jquery solution to show all divs at once modally

Tags: jquery, clone

I have a div container inside which there are several child divs with css float left. However I only make one of these child divs visible at a time. Most of the child divs contain some input fields, radio buttons, etc. The motive to display only one of the child divs at a time was to conserve space. Now I kind of want to display all the divs in one go and not compromise on space. So I am thinking some solution to display all of these modally. I already use jquery-ui stuff in my page. Basically I want to know what can be done here. I can't use the jquery-ui modal dialog boxes since they have their own look and feel. Is it possible to clone the child divs and add it to another div which I programmatically create? Moreover all the child divs are float left. Say there are like 6 child divs. I want it to display 3 in a row...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find one of these plug-ins helpful.

http://fancybox.net/

http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/#